# $find CollapsiblePanelExtender from RegisterStartupScript returns null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, collapsiblepanelextender

I have a .NET 4 web page that contains a User Control with the following:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnExpand" runat="server" Text="Expand..." ClientIDMode="AutoID"
    OnClick="btnExpand_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="btnDummy" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMyPanel" runat="server">
     <p>content</p>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpeMyPanel" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="pnlMyPanel" Collapsed="True" ExpandControlID="btnDummy"
    CollapseControlID="btnDummy" BehaviorID="cpe">
</ajaxToolkit:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
```

When the Expand button is clicked, it executes the following code:

```
protected void btnAddComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = "var cpeMyPanel = $find('" + cpeMyPanel.BehaviorID + "');\r\n" +
                    "if (cpeMyPanel != null)\r\n" +
                    "   cpeMyPanel.expandPanel();\r\n" +
                    "else\r\n" +
                    "   alert(cpeMyPanel is null');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(),
             "Expand", script, true);
}
```

When the script runs on the browser, I get the alert, but $find() always returns null. The end goal is that when the user clicks the button I want to execute some code on the server (such as preparing some content) before expanding the panel.

Any idea what I might be missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

The RegisterStartupScript is executed before the panel is constructed on the client side (search for $create function in the page). The goal is to postpone execution of your script to the point when all compnents are instantiated on the client side. AJAX Control Toolkit uses this [trick](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/edf1fbcb2745#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/ToolkitScriptManager/ToolkitScriptManager.cs):

```
(function () {
    var fn = function () {
        var ajaxControl = $find('AJAX control');
        // do something usefull
    };

    Sys.Application.add_load(fn);
})();
```

I have no experiences with AJAX Toolkit but most likely there is some helper method that take care about script registration. I would start with ToolkitScriptManager.

See this [blog post](http://jakub-linhart.blogspot.com/2012/04/script-registration-labyrinth-startup.html) when you are interested why such a complex solution is needed for such a simple task:).